# Image Histogram not showing- how to fix it?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to create a function that calculates the histogram of an image. When I run the function it doesn't show any errors but the output is not the histogram instead I get an array and the input image.

I tried to run the command separately for the plot. when I do that The figure it is shown but I still don't get the histogram.

def image_hist():

```
im = plt.imread('lena.png')
plt.imshow(im, cmap=plt.cm.gray)

ImageHistogram = np.zeros(256, dtype=np.float64)
PixelNum = im.shape
for i in range (PixelNum[0]):
    for j in range(PixelNum[1]):
        totalvalue = im[j,i]
        ImageHistogram[int(totalvalue*255)] += 1
return ImageHistogram


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(20, 10))
plt.xlabel("Value")
plt.ylabel("pixels Frequency")
plt.title("Histogram Image")
plt.plot(ImageHistogram)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the library PIL and numpy in the following way:

```
 import PIL
 import numpy as np

 im=Image.open('lena.png')
 a = np.array(im.getdata())  # Convert the image into a 2D-Array
 bins_hist = list(range(0,257))  # Number of greyvalues
 histogram = np.histogram(a, bins=bins_hist)
 counts = histogram[0]

 fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
 color = 'tab:red'
 ax1.bar(np.arange(256), counts, color=color)
```